# IOException: Function not implemented. on deploying Heroku with Java 19 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, heroku

On trying to use Java 19 on Heorku with a Spring Boot project, there is an error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project abc: Function not implemented -> [Help 1]

The project works fine on Heroku with Java 18, and locally with Java 19.

Maven used is 3.6.2, which is not the latest, but seems to be the highest value [currently supported by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-maven-version)

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 19... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ------------------------< com.balsamee:dr-api >-------------------------
       [INFO] Building dr-api 0.0.2
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ dr-api ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:list (default-cli) @ dr-api ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ dr-api ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
       [INFO] Copying 28 resources
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  2.236 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-27T15:04:25Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project dr-api: Function not implemented -> [Help 1]
       org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project dr-api: Function not implemented
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
           at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
       Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Function not implemented
           at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:362)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
           at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
       Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Function not implemented
           at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:113)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
           at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
           at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom0 (Native Method)
           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromDirectlyInternal (FileChannelImpl.java:804)
           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromDirectly (FileChannelImpl.java:833)
           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom (FileChannelImpl.java:935)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile (FileUtils.java:861)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile (FileUtils.java:826)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile (FileUtils.java:1888)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile (DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:106)
           at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources (DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:262)
           at org.apache.maven.plugins.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute (ResourcesMojo.java:356)
           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
           at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

system.properties:

```
java.runtime.version=19
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: please execute Maven with `-e` options and provide stack trace

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski thanks, but I am not sure how to tell Heroku to have more options. The maven command is triggered automatically on auto-deploy.

Comment: - https://maven.apache.org/configure.html - you can create `.mvn/maven.config` in project

Comment: You can also execute command locally and try reproduce issue

Comment: Thanks, the project runs locally fine (with maven 3.6.2 and 3.8.4). The full stack trace is updated.

Comment: `Thanks, the project runs locally fine (with maven 3.6.2 and 3.8.4)`

Also with jdk 19 ?

Comment: Yes, locally everything is fine, with Java 18 and 19.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 19 - FileChannelImpl.transferFrom0 - Function not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235391/java-19-filechannelimpl-transferfrom0-function-not-implemented)

Comment: Same issue here. I just opened a ticket on heroku. I'll see what they say.

Comment: Heroku  "support" continues to say it's outside there support policy. With other words = no support. I guess I'll revert back to Java 17/18...or move everything to AWS